# Set CSS definition on an Angular Directive that applies to its children

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material, angular-directive

Im trying to implement a **responsive table directive** in my angular app, which **sets the min and max width and font-size of the columns** in a **MatTable**.

These values are based on the parent containers width, and the number of columns.

The directive gets the column definitions as an input array of strings.(eg.["ordernum","ordername","timestamp"])

Currently the code looks like this:

---

```js
@Input('ResponsiveTable') columns: string[] = [];
...
constructor(
    private el: ElementRef,
    private host: MatTable<any>,
    private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver
  ) {}
....

 ngOnInit(): void {
    //set table style props
    this.el.nativeElement.style.minWidth =
      minCellWidth * this.columns.length + 'px';
    this.el.nativeElement.style.width = tableWidth + '%';

    // //subscriptions
    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.host.contentChanged.subscribe(() =>
        setTimeout(() => this.initStyle())
      )
    );
  }

  
...
  initStyle() {
    //get tableSize
    const parentWidth = this.el.nativeElement.parentNode.clientWidth;
    this.maxColumnWidth =
      parentWidth / this.columns.length > minCellWidth
        ? parentWidth / this.columns.length
        : minCellWidth;

    //set the headers, and maxWidth
    this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('th').forEach((header: any) => {
      header.style.maxWidth = this.maxColumnWidth + 'px';
      header.style.fontSize = `calc(8px + 0.25vw + 0.5vw / ${this.columns.length})`;
      header.style.padding = '6px';
    });

    //set the table cells and maxWidth
    this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('td').forEach((cell: any) => {
      cell.style.maxWidth = this.maxColumnWidth + 'px';
      cell.style.fontSize = `calc(8px + 0.25vw + 0.5vw / ${this.columns.length})`;
    });

    this.initBreakpointObserver();

    this.tableWidth = this.el.nativeElement.width;
  }
```

---

I think this is not efficient, because every time a content change happens, I have to query all the cells and headers, to set their max and min width.

It would be nice to add some CSS to the parent element, that selects all its children mat-cells and mat-headers, and set their size. Sadly I cant use a classic CSS class beacause the size value is based on the number of table columns.

Is there a way to progmatically add a CSS class that selects all the children cells and applies the style to them, even if a new row is added?

Or what could be a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

A better solution (imho) would be to not try to calculate font sizes based on number of columns in the first place.

I would instead set different CSS classes on the grid based on the number of columns. It won't be perfect, but nothing is perfect once you need to change font size based on text width.

If you *really* need to do the calculation, at least try to find a way of running the function only when the current set of columns differs from the last set of columns

Comment: Thank you!  I found a solution with CSS parameters, I'll publish it later, this way theres no need to do calculation when adding a row, and its more efficient. The drawback is that its not supported in old browsers.

Comment: not really a drawback :) there is hardly any usage of browsers that don't support css parameters. I'm curious about the solution you found.

Comment: Hey! If you are curious, then here is my solution: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6p3ewl?file=src/app/responsive-table.directive.ts
It sets the css parameters on the table based on the number of columns. Also transforms mat-fab buttons to mat icon buttons on small screens.
The code is in the responsive-table directive, and in the styles.css file.

Answer (score 0):

Currently applied solution, with the use of CSS parameters:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6p3ewl?file=src/app/responsive-table.directive.ts

This way the properties of the applied class can be set dynamically.